# Why is getpid implemented as a system call?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, system

I'm in the middle of taking my first OS class, so hopefully I don't have any big misconceptions here.

I was wondering why getpid() is implemented as a system call in Linux. As I understand it, certain functions are made into system calls because they access or change information that the OS might want to protect, so they are implemented as a system call in order to transfer control to the kernel.

But as I understand it, getpid() is just returning the process id of the calling process. Is there any case where permission for this information wouldn't be granted? Wouldn't it be safe to simply let getpid() be a normal user function?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This isn't for protection, it's just because process internal structure is implemented in the kernel, not user-mode libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getpid() might be just READING from a location but someone has to WRITE to that location. In order to provide any old process from writing garbage to the location used by the operating system, it need to be protected from user mode access. In order for an application to access that location, it needs to do so in kernel mode. Therefore, it has to be done in as a system call.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to implement getpid() without a system call, is doing one system call first and caching its result. Then every call to getpid() will return that caching value without a system call.

However, the Linux man-pages project explains why getpid() is not cached:

> ```
>    From glibc version 2.3.4 up to and including version 2.24, the glibc
>    wrapper function for getpid() cached PIDs, with the goal of avoiding
>    additional system calls when a process calls getpid() repeatedly.
>    Normally this caching was invisible, but its correct operation relied
>    on support in the wrapper functions for fork(2), vfork(2), and
>    clone(2): if an application bypassed the glibc wrappers for these
>    system calls by using syscall(2), then a call to getpid() in the
>    child would return the wrong value (to be precise: it would return
>    the PID of the parent process).  In addition, there were cases where
>    getpid() could return the wrong value even when invoking clone(2) via
>    the glibc wrapper function.  (For a discussion of one such case, see
>    BUGS in clone(2).)  Furthermore, the complexity of the caching code
>    had been the source of a few bugs within glibc over the years.
>
>    Because of the aforementioned problems, since glibc version 2.25, the
>    PID cache is removed: calls to getpid() always invoke the actual
>    system call, rather than returning a cached value.
> ```

In summary, if getpid() were cached it may return wrong values (even if the cache were done perfectly without allowing any program to write, etc...) and it was a source of bugs
in the past.

Normally you only need a single getpid() call in any process, if you are using the result more than once, save it in a variable (application-level caching!).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As other answers explained, `PID` of a process is kernel's internal data, userspace's process has to access it via syscall, otherwise, it risks being written maliciously.

But, there is a wrong assumption has to be corrected:

> `getpid()` is just returning the process id of the calling process.

In fact, PID is much more complex than what we expected as a result of two aspects:

1. namespace. It's one key fundament of container technology like Docker.
2. thread group, process group, and session group.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any security concern in exposing `pid` to process. The process address space isolation is enforced by the operating system. If I remember correctly the first call to `getpid()` is a system call, but future calls to `getpid()` is cached (by perhaps `libc`) and handled locally.